# How to Search Outlook.com Deleted Mail?

Tags: outlook.com

How can I search within my deleted emails in outlook.com? (Or, for that matter, live.com.) Advanced search allows searches of folders but the "Deleted" folder is not an option.

I am sweeping old retailer emails but want to ensure that no account, order, or shipping emails land in the trash. Yes, I know about marking as "Important," but want to double-check the process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple workaround would be to temporarily move all of your deleted messages to a new folder ("Zombies") and search within that. Then, when you're done with whatever you're moving about, just delete the folder, which will (once again) delete all of the messages within it.

Comment: Hmmm. Thanks Al. Definitely not what i was looking for, but i'll accept it since MS hasn't seen fit to fix this.

Comment: Imperfect, to be sure, but not too burdensome. At least it doesn't require third-party tools. I agree that Gmail's `is:deleted` and similar keywords are quite helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if it's been fixed since this was originally posted, but now if you click on the **Deleted** folder and then run a search you will be searching in the deleted results.